# jQuery slideToggle function not having the desired effect on my input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input box that I'd like to slide up/down so that it looks like it is coming from behind the element above.

My input HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
```

The CSS for the input looks like this:

```
input {
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2980b9;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
$("#dropdown").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").slideToggle(2000);
})
```

Currently, the slide gets stuck at the start/finish, as it seems the height cannot be reduced to 0.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/196509/) is a full example of what happens.

How can I make my input box animate smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wrap the input in a containing element with hidden overflow and animate that one.

```js
$("#dropdown").click(function(){
 $(".input_container").toggleClass('hide');
})
```

```css
#container {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 margin: 100px auto;
 width: 360px;
}

.completed {
 color: gray;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

body {
 font-family: Roboto;
 background: #2BC0E4;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);
 background: linear-gradient(to left, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);
}

input {
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #2980b9;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

input:focus {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 3px solid #2980b9;
 outline: none;
}

::placeholder {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
 background-color: #2980b9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

#dropdown {
 float: right;
}

.input_container{
  height:30px;
  transition: height 2s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.input_container.hide{
  height:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ToDo List</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="container">
  
    <h1>TO-DO LIST <button id = "dropdown">X</button> </h1>
    <div class='input_container'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
    </div>
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I ended up just wrapping my input in a div and using jQuery to animate that the same as I had previously rather than doing a CSS animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition
http://jsfiddle.net/pr2szjhu/1/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo" id="test">
```

JS

```
 $("#dropdown").click(function(){
  if ($('#test').is(':visible')){
     $("#test").removeAttr('placeholder');
     $("input[type='text']").slideToggle(1800);
  }else{
     $("input[type='text']").slideToggle(1800,function() {
         $("#test").attr('placeholder','Add New Todo');
    });

  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite the effect i desired. There's still a jump at the end.